# Openpyxl deleting cell if it is equal to an another worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, openpyxl

I just trying to delete the value if it is equal. Code explain further I think.
I seen some post about this topic but I don't get it, it is all about delete a cell in special order (number). I am trying to delete a value if its equal to an element in my List in the **Worksheet 'Keyword Brainstorm'**.

Code:

```
def checkBrainstormWithTrashcan():
    
    trashcanList = list()
    brainstormList = list()

    brainstormKeyword = wb['Keyword Brainstorm']
    
    for row in brainstormKeyword.rows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != None:
                brainstormList.append(cell.value)

    
    trashcanKeyword = wb['Trashcan']
    for row in trashcanKeyword.rows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != None:
                trashcanList.append(cell.value)
    
    print(brainstormList)
    print(trashcanList)

    for brain in brainstormList:
        for trash in trashcanList:
            if brain == trash:
                print(brain)
                #trying to remove here. the value of brain is exactly the values 
                 which are equal
```

I hope you guys can help and if you have an suggestion or site about removing Elements it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to delete a cell value i.e. make it empty if the `cell.value` matches with a element in  `trashcanList` or `brainstormList`.

Based on above assumption, below is an example that illustrates above. I trust you will be able to use logic/code to suit your exact needs.

We can use `openpyxl` module to manipulate `xls` or `xlsx` files.
See more on [openpyxl here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl).

I created a file `test.xlsx` (see in figure) that has data in two columns (1,2).

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'test.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Keyword Brainstorm']
```

We read workbook to `wb` handle and worksheet to `sheet`.

Next, based on assumption, I created two static list with data as below.

```
trashcanList  = ['big', 'fox']
brainstormList  = ['white', 'bear']
```

Next, we get max row and column values within worksheet (to make iterating through row/column dynamic).

```
row_count = sheet.max_row
column_count = sheet.max_column
```

Then  we iterate through rows first, then column and check if value in cell is in either of list. If yes, replace with blank char.

```
for current_row in xrange(1,row_count+1):
    for current_col in xrange(1,column_count+1):
        _cell = sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=current_col)
        if _cell.value in trashcanList or _cell.value in brainstormList:
            _cell.value = ''
```

Finally save modified file (with new name , you can use same name as well , but it will overwrite original content). Then close the file handle.

```
wb.save('outTest.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

**Result:**
In result you can see values from the list deleted in output file `outtest.xlsx` (replaced by blank).

[image]

Comment: Hi, if my answer solves the problem then do consider accepting it by clicking check mark next to answer. This way the question will appear as resolved rather than hanging open.